# Using the Big Pipe approach for listing pages that are driven by Solr Index

Tags: 8, performance, search

We are working on a website where we might end up having thousands/lakhs of nodes. So we are planning on using Apache Solr for the listing pages as well.

Having researched a little bit about Big Pipe I was curious if we can use the Big Pipe approach for listing pages that are driven by Solr Index and if Drupal 8 Search/Solr module already supports it.

Comment: Depends on how your listings are configured in regard to caching. Big pipe is only a delivery mechanism. Basically, the dynamic page cache is underneath, so not that much changes(as I understand it). So as long as you'll use proper cache tags you should be fine...BUT keep in mind that for anonymous users the page_cache will cache the whole page so you'll have to use JS to load the content or disable page_cache on those pages so that dynamic_page_cache can take over.

Comment: @IvanJaros Please share this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you want to achieve?

That you can scroll endlessly through your nodes and don't have to click on pager links?

That's not related to the big pipe stuff.

Instead, you'll need a views pager plugin for that, e.g. https://www.drupal.org/project/views_infinite_scroll. There is a Drupal 8 version but I haven't used it yet, so I don't know if it's stable.